# How i can Execute string as C# code in sandbox

Tags: c#, .net-core

Anyone knows how i can create a Sandbox to execute string as c# code in net5 or net6?

For example i have STRING:

```
public int WhichBigger(int param1, int param2)
{
return param1 > param2 ? param1 : param2;
}
```

I want to execute this string as c# code, pass params to it and capture the answer. Like

```
var function = "public int WhichBigger...";
function  = function.replace("param1","10");
function  = function.replace("param1","20");
var result = sandbox.execute(funcion)
//result is 20
```

I found this for net 4.XXX: https://github.com/JamesTryand/ConsolR

I can't do by Roslyn Scripting because there is a possibility of code injection by other users. I need sandbox, only interact inside it. If anyone inject "delete C" the sandbox wouldn't do anything because it doesn't have c, I guess I'm explaining myself

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK the Roslyn script API is sandboxed (you need to explicitly provide "globals" to a script to be able to access other objects)

Comment: FYI - `Math.Max(a,b)` does the exact same thing as your code.

Comment: _"I can't do by Roslyn Scripting because there is a possibility of code injection by other users"_ - if you don't want to run user-supplied expressions then why do you want `eval()`-like functionality at all? Just write C# in the first place...